# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for url+dbName,UserId=?&password=?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am trying to connect mysql database with java (eclipse) 
here is my code

```
Controller.java

package classes;



import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Controller{

    public static boolean validate(String userId, String Pass){
        boolean status = false;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
        String dbName = "meeting_planner";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String UserId = "123";
        String password = "hhh";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("url+dbName,UserId=?&password=?");
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from administrator where AId=? and Password=?");
            pst.setString(1,userId);
            pst.setString(2, Pass);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            status = rs.next();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            if(con!=null){
                try {
                    con.close();
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(pst!=null){
                try {
                    pst.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

AND administrator.java is

```
package classes;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class administrator extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String i = request.getParameter("Userid");
        String p = request.getParameter("userpassword");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null)
            session.setAttribute("Administrator Id",i);
        if(Controller.validate(i,p)){
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("creat_date.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else {
            out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry User id or Password error!</p>");
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }


    }
}
```

mysql database name is meeting_planner 
table name : administrator
and attributes name are AId,Password,Name,Email
index.jsp is a login page it gets the values of attributes  AId and Password and authenticate the data from database and farward the control to creat_date.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("url+dbName,UserId=?&password=?");
```

to

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, UserId, password);
```

You should use camelCase to name your variables.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: thanks i just edit my code ... but now it gave another error that is "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '123'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: That means `hhh` is not the correct password for user `123`. Make sure the user and/or password is correct.

Comment: I just changed the userId="123" to 111 and password="hhh" to sadia as in the database there is only one record that is AId=111 and Password=sadia but now it gave error message that is "An internal error occurred during: "Launching client".
java.lang.NullPointerException" and in console it gave error "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '111'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: @SadiaAsghar  That message suggests that you are adding in some stray `'` characters somewhere.  Anyway, are you able to log into the database directly using the username and password that you provided to the program?

Comment: This user name and password is not for  database login. In the administrator table there are attributes userId and Password.i just want to login on the basis of these two attributes authentication

Comment: To do that you need a valid connection to the `SQL` server. I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is possible, if it is try the following approach: #1 Connect to the database #2 retrieve the  username and password you want #2 save the values in a variable #4 create a new connection with the user data you just retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use String concatenation. Try changing from:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("url+dbName,UserId=?&password=?");
```

To:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, UserId, password);
```

Comment: OP's current code is not even String concatenation, it is a plain String that looks like a wrong String variable concatenation.

Comment: thanks i just edit my code ... but now it gave another error thata is "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '123'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"